# Do rolling mean in 2 different columns and make one column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'hometeam_id': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 6, 6: 1, 7: 3, 8: 2},
    'awayteam_id': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6, 3: 3, 4: 5, 5: 1, 6: 4, 7: 6, 8: 5},
    'home_score': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 5, 6: 4, 7: 7, 8: 8},
    'away_score': {0: 5, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 4}})
```

I need to do rolling average on last 2 values for each row. But the trick is I need the total goals by id. For example team 1 played 2 games as home and 1 game as away. I need to add 2 new columns that will show total goals by home team and away team. For example for team 1 the 2 new colums would look like this.

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'home_id': {0: 1, 1: 6, 2: 1},
 'away_id': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 4},
 'home_score': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 4},
 'away_score': {0: 5, 1: 2, 2: 1},
 'total_home': {0: 1.0, 1: nan, 2: 1.5},
 'total_away': {0: nan, 1: 2.0, 2: nan}})
```

Ignore the na values I have not calculated them for other teams, just calculations for team 1. Basically, in this format I need team average goals for last 2 games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```
df['total_home'] = (df.groupby('hometeam_id')
                      .home_score
                      .rolling(2, min_periods=0)
                      .mean()
                      .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                   )

df['total_away'] = (df.groupby('awayteam_id')
                      .away_score
                      .rolling(2, min_periods=0)
                      .mean()
                      .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                   )
```

Output:

```
   hometeam_id  awayteam_id  home_score  away_score  total_home  total_away
0            1            2           1           5         1.0         5.0
1            3            4           4           1         4.0         1.0
2            5            6           3           2         3.0         2.0
3            2            3           2           3         2.0         3.0
4            4            5           1           4         1.0         4.0
5            6            1           5           2         5.0         2.0
6            1            4           4           1         2.5         1.0
7            3            6           7           2         5.5         2.0
8            2            5           8           4         5.0         4.0
```

Comment: I understand the same thing, also Gz on 30k!

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a `transform`:

**Solution**

```
df['total_home'] = df.groupby('hometeam_id')['home_score'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2, 1).mean())
df['total_away'] = df.groupby('awayteam_id')['away_score'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2, 1).mean())
```

**Output**

```
print(df.to_string())

   hometeam_id  awayteam_id  home_score  away_score  total_home  total_away
0            1            2           1           5         1.0           5
1            3            4           4           1         4.0           1
2            5            6           3           2         3.0           2
3            2            3           2           3         2.0           3
4            4            5           1           4         1.0           4
5            6            1           5           2         5.0           2
6            1            4           4           1         2.5           1
7            3            6           7           2         5.5           2
8            2            5           8           4         5.0           4
```